How to convert Win32 hIcon IconHandle for use in WinUI 3
I need to convert default Win32 Icon Handles of type HICON to be used within WinUI 3 Applications.
Is there something like BitmapSource to be used to convert into a BitmapImage?
I know, I can use embedded Icon Resources like this:
BitmapImage AppIconImage= new(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/app.ico"));

But this doesn't work for runtime Icons when using Shell32 Icons.
